# Alternative for HID API to implement Game controller for MacOS application?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, iokit, gamecontroller

I am working on a game targeting Mac and iOS, which has game controller support implemented recently.
I use **Game Controller** (GC) framework for PS4/ XBox controllers and **HID API** included in **IOKit** for the others (Steelseries Nimbus and non-mainstream brands), simply because their controllers do not seem to work with GC Framework.

After submitting to review, the game has been rejected for the reason of **"The app references non-public symbols"** which list out all of the functions related to HID API used in the game, including officially documented functions which considered essential for the implementation, such as:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1438383-iohidmanagercreate?language=objc
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1438369-iohidmanageropen?language=objc
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1438399-iohidmanagerregisterdevicematchi?language=objc

I have contact Apple Developer support about this, but everything I received was auto-reply emails state that they can only provide administrative level support and advice me to direct this question toward forums and community, thus, I'm here.

If you happen to have an alternative solution for this or any experience regard similar issues please do consider leaving an answer or comment.

Thank you,

**P/S: Please also comment if you have a source listing out the public API(s) that developers can use. I have been following the idea "if it's documented, then I can use" but after this incident, it seems to not be the case.**

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question as such. (I'm not an expert on the Mac App Store) However: The way to get Apple to talk to you about this is by filing a Developer Tech Support incident. You can do this via the ["Code-Level Support" section](https://developer.apple.com/account/#/support/) in your developer account area. In theory you need to pay for these, but you get 2 for free every year with your paid developer account. If DTS cannot give you an answer, you'll be refunded the incident too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip pmdj, If no one have an answer for this I will check to see if we can spend a ticket for this issue.